# bxSlider Uncaught TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bxslider

am using this jquery but for some reason am getting this error

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.bxslider.css" />

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.slider1').bxSlider({
```

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
              slideWidth: 960,
              maxSlides: 1,
              slideMargin: 0,
              captions: true,
              auto: true,
              autoControls: true
          });
      });
        </script>
```

anyone had this before or no?

Thanks

Comment: can you show complete code?

Comment: the error is in that function

Comment: where have you included js files??

Comment: top of the page with all the other scripts as seen above

Comment: are you sure the url fo bxSlider file is correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59667/discussion-between-al123-and-ehsan-sajjad).

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
```

instead of:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Wordpress uses jQuery in noConflict mode by default. You need to reference it using jQuery as the variable name, not $, e.g. use

```
jQuery(document);
```

instead of

```
$(document);
```

You can easily wrap this up in a self executing function so that $ refers to jQuery again (and avoids polluting the global namespace as well), e.g.

```
(function ($) {
   $(document);
}(jQuery));
```